# Fullcalendar groupId Event Object in v3

Tags: fullcalendar, fullcalendar-3, fullcalendar-4

In Fullcalendar v4 there is a new groupId event object for moving multiple grouped events together. We have quite a complex customised v3 installation of Fullcalendar and Scheduler and don't want to have to upgrade just to get the groupId functionality.

Is there a way to port this functionality to v3 (eg. a section of code which can be added to fullcalendar.js)?

Comment: Probably yes, if you write enough code. Most things are possible if you write all the necessary code.

Comment: Not sure you would need to modify the fullCalendar source though. Someone asked about this concept a few months ago I'm sure. Basically the idea was to set a custom property on all events so you could associate them together, almost identical to the groupId really. Then handle the callback when an event has finished being dragged/resized, and use the provided delta to know how much it has moved. Then get all events with the same groupID and manually change their start/end times by the same amount. That was the gist of it anyway